# Does my remote server (Amazon EC2) need 2 different servers running to run EmberJS and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, ember.js

It seems that for EmberJS we need a server to run, usually on localhost:4040.

Spring Boot needs its own server for run of coarse on localhost:8080.

Is this really necessary to run 2 different servers on a remote server or even recommended?

Why can't I just get the javascript from the EmberJS and put it in my Spring Boot project. As in go to the static resources folder and put the EmberJS files there?

Why do we really need a server for EmberJS in the first place? It's front end code to be read by a browser?

If none of this is recommended then how do we use EmberJS and Spring Boot together on one server? Everywhere I see uses EmberJS on its own server and does a cross request to localhost:8080 for spring boot.

I am relatively new to Web App Dev so some jargon may go over my head.

Answer (score 1):

EmberJS server its for development only. If you want to make a release version, you need to do a production build. Then you can package the generated files in your SpringBoot jar.

```
ember build --env production
```

> Once the build finishes, you'll find all of the concatenated and
>   minified assets in your application's dist/ directory.

Source: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/quick-start/#toc_building-for-production

Answer (score 1):

I use Spring Boot with ember.js. You don't *need* two servers, but I personally prefer to use a SSL terminating reverse proxy with Spring Boot (Apache or nginx). I do this for a number of reasons (mostly performance with regard to SSL and serving static assets, as well as easier configuration in general for SSL, compression, and caching). It's IMO a far better production setup.

Anyway, for apache, here's the configuration I used in `centos` inside of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8080/api
  ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8080/api
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myhostname.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
FallbackResource /index.html
Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
```

In the above, replace `myhostname.com` with your host name. What the above configuration does is proxy all https requests to `/api` to my locally running Spring Boot tomcat server over plain http(I use the embedded tomcat which I deploy as an executable jar). In `application.properties` I specify that my REST servlet should run on `/api`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api/
```

The rewrite config just rewrites all http requests as https which is a good practice. Finally, the `FallbackResource /index.html` is very important. This configures my server to always return ember's `index.html` file if my server cannot find the resource. See, let's say you have a `foo` route. When someone visits `/foo` in their browser, it's going to make an `HTTP GET` to your web server asking for the `/foo` resource (which doesn't exist) b/c the routing in Ember is handled by Ember itself. What you instead must do is return the `index.html` file which will then pull in the necessary assets that ultimately will invoke the necessary Ember routing code on the client side to show the `foo` route.

So, this means we need to put `index.html` somewhere that `apache` can serve. Your `apache` config will have a line somewhere like `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` which is the directory that apache will serve for `/`. This is where we must put our production ready ember build which includes the `index.html` file.

Taking a step back, if you only ever run `ember s` locally, you may not even know about the existence of `index.html`. But the bundled server used with this command is not a production tool. For production, you must first build your app:

`ember build --environment=production`

In your `ember-cli-build.js` file, you will probably want `production` only optimizations such as:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    minifyJS: EmberApp.env() === 'production',
    minifyCSS: EmberApp.env() === 'production',
    fingerprint: {
        enabled: EmberApp.env() === 'production'
    }
});
```

This produces a `/dist` folder which has the `index.html` and all assets like your javascript, ember's javascript, css files, etc. You will want to copy the contents of this folder to the directory you defined as `DocumentRoot` (`/var/www/html`). Now, `apache` can serve your Ember App and proxy all of your api requests to your spring boot app (which mustn't run on privileged ports like 80 or 443).

You can now separate your front end ember deployments from your backend deployments which is a huge win. Your ember deployments require zero backend downtime!