# When packaging an SPA (and no Java code) into a WAR, how to serve the index.html for every URL except for those that match actual asset files?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, build, single-page-application, war

I have a single-page webapplication, that when built must be installable into a java-ee application server, such as Glassfish. That is, I should package it into a WAR.

This single-page webapplication is strongly separated from its backend application, it should be buildable and deployable by itself. That is, the WAR only should and will include the single-page webapplication.

If possible, I would like to solve this without having any Java code.

In the case of a single-page application, the URL routing should function like this:

1. If the requested URL matches a static asset file (html, js, css, etc.), then that file should be served.
2. In any other case the `index.html` should be served.

When the second point does not apply, the application (by default) can only be accessed at its entry point (`index.html`). And not with URLs pointing directly to any subroutes.

There is a workaround, since In Ember.js it is possible to set an option to use hash based subroute URLs. But this has its limiting drawbacks, and I'd like to entirely avoid.

The solution I currently have however is working only by switching on said workaround. I'm using maven and the `maven-assembly-plugin` to achieve this.

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>My App</name>
  <build>
    <finalName>finalName</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- assemble static content -->
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>static.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

static.xml

(`dist` is the directory where ember-cli puts the compiled assets, that I need to include.)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
  <id>static</id>
  <formats>
    <format>war</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>dist</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>WEB-INF/*</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>WEB-INF</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
      <outputDirectory>/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I also have a web.xml inside the WEB-INF folder, but this is essentially empty.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

So to summarize the question: Is it possible to have said routing logic without writing any Java code, that is without any "gluing" or "middleman" server side module?

Comment: you might get better answers if you targeted an actual java-ee tag. For `ember`, you run `ember build --environment=production` and then as you said, fallback to the `index.html` file when the resource isn't found. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929463/does-my-remote-server-amazon-ec2-need-2-different-servers-running-to-run-ember/55949439#55949439) doesn't answer yours exactly but it should give you the right terminology hopefully to find out how to fallback to `index.html` within your app server (which mosts spas require)

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work (my frontend is angular, but it will work with any other, provided it is not picky about the return status 404). My web.xml:

```
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

It means: when a resource is not found (not a servlet, or a jsp, or a static file or else), then serve "/index.html" as the 404 page.

There are two downsides though:
1. any resource your app happens to ask and the server doesn't have (be it an image, a stylesheet or else), will get a full /index.html in response;
2. it could be a bit misleading (to the browser) to get a fully working app after a 404.